# How do i merge local branch with remote branch with git?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have checked a branch named **develop** then i create a local branch from develop named **anomalie**
so now i have in local 2 branch **develop** and **anomalie**.

i want to execute the followings merge operation:

- merge anaomalie into  release // release is a remote branch
- merge release into  develop   // release is a remote branch
- merge develop into nextgeneration // next generation is a remote branch

can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is your Git provider/repository (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.) ?

Comment: You do not need to merge local branch into the remote. Create local branch for remote release and next generation branches, and then merge anomalie into release (locally), then local release into local develop; and then local develop into local next generation. After merges, simply push the branches to remote. This is safe approach - so if something will go wrong with merge, you'll find and fix it locally.

Answer (score 0):

from your description I expect a `git branch -a` to lead to the following state (assuming your `remote` is called `origin`):

```
* anomalie 
develop
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/release
remotes/origin/nextgeneration
```

Now, starting from your branch `anomalie` you'd do the following:

(1) `merge anaomalie into release // realse is a remote branch`

```
git checkout release
git merge --no-ff anomalie
git push
```

(2) `merge release into develop // release is a remote branch`

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff release
git push
```

(3) `merge develop into nextgeneration // netx generation is a remote branch`

```
git checkout nextgeneration
git merge --no-ff develop
git push
```

There might obviously be merge conflicts here and there and I am also assuming your local branch `develop` is already set up to track the remote branch `origin/develop`.
Regarding `--no-ff`: I suggest that to make sure there is always a merge commit, but that's just an opinion.

Cheers,
Dominic